# Exchaning one src attribute with another src attribute via jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, src

I have to images and I'd like to switch the src attributes of the images, when one is clicked:

Before:

```
<img src="1.jpg" class="image1" />
<img src="2.jpg" class="image2" />
```

After clicking on image 1 or 2:

```
<img src="2.jpg" class="image1" />
<img src="1.jpg" class="image2" />
```

I can change the src of the clicked image, but I don't seem to be able to store the original src-attribute in any way to pass it to the other image.

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder what the use case is for this sort of thing.

Comment: Of course this is just an excerpt. It's an image-gallery. The first image is shown big, when you click on a thumbnail, the thumbnail is shown instead of the big image. So what to do to see the first pic again? I need to store the src for the big image somewhere (by exchanging the two images).

Answer (score 2):

You won't believe but you can store it in a 3rd variable!!

```
var img1 = $('.image1'),
    img2 = $('.image2');

var originalSrc = img1.attr('src');

img1.attr('src', img2.attr('src'));
img2.attr('src', originalSrc);
```

Comment: That's what I tried, my code:

`$('.image1').click(function() { orgSource = $(this).attr("src); alert(orgSource); $(this).parents(".node").find(".image2").attr("src", orgSource);`

...gives me TWO alerts, one with the first and one with the second src...

Comment: @user1632757: reproduce that on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I know this is pretty basic but it was a bit of a revelation!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Id').click(function(){
$('.image1').attr('src','2.jpg');
$('.image2').attr('src','1.jpg');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following with jQuery. More info can be found here:

http://jquery.com

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0">
$(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
   $(this).closest("img").attr("src",$(this).attr("src"));
  });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way:

```
$('.image1 , .image2').click(function() {
   if ($(this).prev().length) {
      temp = $(this).attr('src');
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).prev().attr('src') );
      $(this).prev().attr('src',temp);
   } else {
      temp = $(this).attr('src');
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).next().attr('src') );
      $(this).next().attr('src',temp);
   }
});
```